# Specifying transparency in browserconfig.xml

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, live-tile, pinned-site

Windows Phone 8.1 supports transparent start screen tiles, and apps can make use of the `backgroundColor=transparent` setting in their manifest.

However, for Pinned sites either the `<meta>` tag in the HTML markup, or the browserconfig.xml should be used, containing the `<TileColor>` element. Is it possible to specify that the tile should be left transparent in this case? I tried using the value `transparent` or removing the element, but this results in the tile having black background.